# JavaScript/jQuery tooltip function using "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tooltip, this

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/awpnd6L1/1/

Was wondering if there was a way I could create a function in JavaScript, so that I'm not having to copy the mouseenter code each time I need a "More Info" tooltip. Is this even possible?

Below is the JavaScript I'm looking to condense into a function so that I don't have to copy it several times.

```
  jQuery(".bspaMoreInfo").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').data('timeoutId'));
    jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').show(200);

}).mouseleave(function(){
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});

jQuery(".bspaMoreInfoText").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
```

Hope this makes sense x3

Comment: You should delegate event. That's said, i'm not sure what behaviour you are expecting in your jsFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom jQuery plugin for this job. This is the very natural approach in term of handling repetitive code.

```
$.fn.moreInfo = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

        var $text = $(this).next();

        $(this).mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout($text.data('timeoutId'));
            $text.show(200);
        })
        .mouseleave(function () {
            $text.data('timeoutId', setTimeout(function () {
                $text.hide(200);
            }, 650));
        });

        $text.mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout($text.data('timeoutId'));
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $text.data('timeoutId', setTimeout(function () {
                $text.hide(200);
            }, 650));
        });
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bspaMoreInfo").moreInfo();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/awpnd6L1/3/

Comment: You're a star! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/awpnd6L1/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(".bspaMoreInfo").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).next().data('timeoutId'));
        $('.bspaMoreInfoText').hide(200);
      $(this).next().show(200);

    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).next().hide(200);
        }, 650);
       $(this).next().data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
    });

    jQuery(".bspaMoreInfoText").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').data('timeoutId'));
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').hide(200);
        }, 650);
        jQuery('.bspaMoreInfoText').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry.. that's the code I already have (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
function MouseEnter(ctrl) {
    clearTimeout($(ctrl).data('timeoutId'));
    $(ctrl).show(200);

}

function MouseLeave(ctrl) {
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $(ctrl).hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $(ctrl).data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 

}

$(".bspaMoreInfo").mouseenter(function () {
    MouseEnter($(".bspaMoreInfoText"));
}).mouseleave(function() {
    MouseLeave(this);
}));

$(".bspaMoreInfoText").mouseenter(function () {
    MouseEnter($(".bspaMoreInfoText"));
}).mouseleave(function() {
    MouseLeave($(".bspaMoreInfoText"));
}));
```